# Как корректно импортировать функцию, возвращающую промис? Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть функция, возвращающая промис. В файле, где она создана, всё прекрасно работает.
Но когда импортируешь в другой файл, там ошибка

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

**Вот код функции и пример:**

```html
function fileToArray(Object) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream(Object.file),
            crlfDelay: Infinity
        });
        rl.on('line', line => Object.array.push(line));
        rl.on('close', () => resolve(Object.array));
        rl.on('error', err => reject(err))
    });
}

fileToArray({file:"./maleNames.txt",array:[]}).then(lines => console.log(lines));
//^^ работает, выдаёт массив

module.exports = fileToArray; //экспортная строка
```

**а вот запуск в файле, где импортирована**

```html
const fileToArray = require('./myLib');

fileToArray({file:"./maleNames.txt",array:[]}).then(lines => console.log(lines));
```

***в консоли вижу ошибку:***

```html
fileToArray({file:"./maleNames.txt",array:[]}).then(lines => console.log(lines));
                                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Comment: Возможно, к проблеме не относится, но вроде бы использовать `Object` как имя параметра может быть рисковано, так как это перезаписывает глобальный `Object`.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty спасибо, учту. Переименую параметр

Comment: Но я не могу воспроизвести вашу проблему. Создав модуль с вашим примером, у меня получается его экспортировать и получить результат. Возможно, вы сократили пример и пропустили при этом причину ошибки.

Comment: А в myLib кроме этой функции ещё что-то есть?

Comment: такое поведение возможно только если `fileToArray` не возвращала ничего

Answer (score 0):

Победил проблему, переписав пару экспорт-импорт иначе:

Экспорт из оригинального файла\\ **module.exports.fta = fileToArray;**

Импорт в рабочий файл\\ **let myLib = require('./myLib');** ...далее **myLib.fta()**